# Azure AD B2C error $i2e.sendDataWithRetry is not a function on login.microsoft.com

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Did anyone face such javascript exception on microsoft.com domain?

$i2e.sendDataWithRetry is not a function

This happened when a user logged in into the site using azure ad b2c.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Is this simply for signing into the Azure portal or signing into your custom application?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you tried to invoke a function, but there is no such function in the object. Probably there is a field with this name, but not a function. This usually happens if the function is named or invoked incorrectly.